# Redirect query string to url using .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I am trying to redirect this url:

```
https://www.example.com/?category=1&page=1
```

to this url:

```
https://www.example.com/?category=1
```

I have 12 categories, can i redirect all with one code?
for example i have

```
https://www.example.com/?category=2&page=1 => https://www.example.com/?category=2
https://www.example.com/?category=3&page=1 => https://www.example.com/?category=3
.
.
.
```

my code doesn't work:

```
RewriteEngine On 
# RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^\/index\.php$ 
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^category=([0-9]*)&page=1 
RewriteRule ^(.*)category=([0-9]*)&page=1$ https://www.example.com/?category=([0-9]*)%1 [R=302,L]
```

I have already redirected all index.php with this code and works:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/index\.php 
RewriteRule ^(.*)index.php$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^category=([0-9]*)&page=1 
> RewriteRule ^(.*)category=([0-9]*)&page=1$ https://www.example.com/?category=([0-9]*)%1 [R=302,L]
> ```

The `RewriteRule` *pattern* (first argument) matches against the URL-path only, not the query string. You are already matching the query string in the `RewriteCond` directive, so there's no need to do this twice anyway.

If there is no URL-path (ie. all requests target the document root) as per your examples then you can simplify the *pattern* and there is no need to capture the URL-path.

Including the regex `([0-9]*)` in the *substitution* string (2nd argument) makes no sense. This is an "oridinary" string, not a regex.

Try the following instead:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(category=\d{1,2})&page=1$
RewriteRule ^$ /?%1 [R=302,L]
```

Instead of capturing just the `category` value, we might as well capture the complete name/value pair and avoid repetition.

`\d` is a shorthand character class and is the same as `[0-9]`. I've also changed this so that it matches just 1 or 2 digits (since you say you only have 12 categories). Using the `*` quantifier would allow an *empty* `category` parameter.

Note that this matches the document root only, as per your examples. ie. it won't match `example.com/foo?category=1&page1`. And only URLs that contain `page=1` as a 2nd URL param.

You don't need to include the full absolute URL in the target, unless you want to include this as part of your canonical redirect.